# boost.log error occured while using sink.set_filter

Tags: boost-log

I use boost.log for my project.
But when I tried to set filter for sinks, compilation errors came.

code are simple:

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(MyTag, "My_Tag", std::string);
BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_CTOR_ARGS(
        my_logger
        , boost::log::sources::channel_logger_mt< >
        , (boost::log::keywords::channel = "default"))

typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<
            boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend > TextSink;
boost::shared_ptr< TextSink > logSink = boost::make_shared< TextSink >();
auto backSink = boost::make_shared<std::ofstream>("default.log");

!!! compilation error, no add_attribute in channel_logger !!!
my_logger::get().add_attribute("My_Tag"
                , boost::log::attributes::constant<String>("My_Tag"));

logSink->set_filter(
                    boost::log::expressions::has_attr(MyTag)
!!! compilation error, invalid operand expression between attribute_actor and std::string !!!
                    && boost::log::expressions::attr<std::string>("My_Tag")==std::string("My_Tag")
!!! compilation error, invalid operand expression between attribute_keyword<tag::MyTag> and char[7] !!!
                    && MyTag=="My_Tag"
```

I also tried to define filter function, but got following error:

```
bool my_filter(
            boost::log::value_ref< std::string
!!! compilation error, no tag_attr in boost::log::expressions::tag !!!
            , boost::log::expressions::tag::tag_attr > const& tag)
{
    return level >= warning || tag == "IMPORTANT_MESSAGE";
}
```

By the way, I also have following error, but this error will disappear if all other compilation errors were solved.

```
!!! no open_record in severity_logger_mt !!!
BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, normal) << "A regular message";
```

### could anyone help me?

---

full code :

```
#include <boost/phoenix/operator.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/channel_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/attribute.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/attribute_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/log/keywords/filter.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/predicates.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/attr_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/attr.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks.hpp>

BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_CTOR_ARGS(
        my_channel_logger
        , boost::log::sources::channel_logger_mt< >
        , (boost::log::keywords::channel = "channel"))

BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(MyTag, "My_Tag", std::string);

typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<
            boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend > TextSink;
static boost::shared_ptr< TextSink > logSink = boost::make_shared< TextSink >();
static auto backSink = boost::make_shared<std::ofstream>("output.log");
void func() {

    !!! compilation error, no 'open_record' in channel_logger_mt !!!
    BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL(my_channel_logger::get(), "channel")<<"channel log";

    !!! compilation error, no add_attribute in channel_logger !!!
    my_channel_logger::get().add_attribute("My_Tag"
       , boost::log::attributes::constant<String>("My_Tag"));
}
```

compilation error for `no open_record in channel_logger_mt`:

```
***.cpp:87:5: error: no member named 'open_record' in 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt6::sources::channel_logger_mt<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >'
channel_feature.hpp:236:41: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL'
channel_feature.hpp:231:5: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_LOG_STREAM_CHANNEL'
record_ostream.hpp:566:5: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS'
record_ostream.hpp:555:50: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS_INTERNAL'
```

compilation error for `no add_attribute in channel_logger_mt`:

```
***.cpp:76:31: error: no member named 'add_attribute' in 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt6::sources::channel_logger_mt<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you're missing `#include`s in your code.

```
!!! compilation error, no add_attribute in channel_logger !!!
my_logger::get().add_attribute("My_Tag"
                , boost::log::attributes::constant<String>("My_Tag"));
```

`add_attribute` is defined by [`basic_composite_logger`](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/ca227bc2f30d65f14719a674247728647caa2b2f/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp#L378), from which `channel_logger_mt` [derives](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/ca227bc2f30d65f14719a674247728647caa2b2f/include/boost/log/sources/channel_logger.hpp#L46). You need to include `boost/log/sources/channel_logger.hpp`.

```
!!! compilation error, invalid operand expression between attribute_actor and std::string !!!
                    && boost::log::expressions::attr<std::string>("My_Tag")==std::string("My_Tag")
!!! compilation error, invalid operand expression between attribute_keyword<tag::MyTag> and char[7] !!!
                    && MyTag=="My_Tag"
```

Most likely, you're missing an include of `boost/phoenix/operator.hpp`. Or you can include `boost/log/expressions.hpp`, which automatically includes it for you.

```
!!! no open_record in severity_logger_mt !!!
BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, normal) << "A regular message";
```

Same as with `channel_logger_mt`. You need to include `boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp`.

Note that for every component in the docs, there is a list of associated Boost.Log headers in the very beginning of the section. [Here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html#log.detailed.sources.severity_level_logger) is an example for the severity logger.

---

**Update on 2019-07-03:**

Your full code compiles, if the following includes are added:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/make_shared_object.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
```

I also had to remove the "!!!" lines and use `std::string` instead of `String` in the `constant` attribute.

In general, you have to include a header for every component you use in your code.

Comment: after #include <boost/phoenix/operator.hpp>.           logSink->set_filter(
                    boost::log::expressions::has_attr(MyTag)  && MyTag=="My_Tag") passed.     But I have include <severity_logger.hpp/channel_logger.hpp> before, "no 'open_record' / 'add_abbtribute' " problem still exist

Comment: Maybe you should post the complete code and compiler errors then.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!